# Importing image from external URL using Magmi datapump

Tags: php, magento, magmi

I am using Magmi datapump to import some products into Magento.

So far i have this:

```
require_once("../../magmi/inc/magmi_defs.php");
require_once("../../magmi/integration/inc/magmi_datapump.php");

$dp = Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");

$dp->beginImportSession("Default","create");

$newProductData = array(
    'type'                  => 'simple',
    'sku'                   => "test-simple",
    'qty'                   => 1000,
    'color'                 => 'Brown',
    'price'                 => 10,
    'name'                  => 'test simple',
    'tax_class_id'          => 1,
    'is_in_stock'           => 1,
    'store'                 => 'admin',
    'economic_productgroup' => 700,
    'image'                 => '+http://blogs.smh.com.au/entertainment/getflickd/44655_native.jpeg.jpg',
    'small_image'           => 'http://blogs.smh.com.au/entertainment/getflickd/44655_native.jpeg.jpg',
    'thumbnail'             => 'http://blogs.smh.com.au/entertainment/getflickd/44655_native.jpeg.jpg'
);

$dp->ingest($newProductData);

$dp->endImportSession();
```

All attributes are getting imported correctly, except image. This does not work.

This is screenshot from "Default" profile.

[image]

[image]

Magmi is installed here: http://www.example.com/import/magmi/web/magmi.php

Why are import of my images not working?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by creating new profile in webinterface with exact same settings as i had in "default" profile. Not sure why though.